# Breadth First Search on numpy image array for consecutive region/hole detection

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, breadth-first-search

I have a numpy array that looks like the following

```
arr = np.array([[-1, -1, -1,  0, -1]
               [ -1, -1, -1,  0, -1]
               [ -1,  0, -1, -1,  0]
               [ -1,  0, -1, -1, -1]
               [ -1, -1, -1, -1,  0]])
```

I want each consecutive region marked 0 to be a different value such that my array would end up looking like this. Notice that adjacent diagonals get included.

```
arr = np.array([[ -1, -1, -1,  1, -1]
                [ -1, -1, -1,  1, -1]
                [ -1,  2, -1, -1,  1]
                [ -1,  2, -1, -1, -1]
                [ -1, -1, -1, -1,  3]])
```

One way of doing this could be through a breadth first search. Is there any convenient way to do this or is there an easier method available?

Comment: Looks like a 2d matrix representation of directed graph, where -1 is no edge and 0 is edge. You could run DFS in a node if it contains 0 and is not visited. For each non visited edge found increase count by 1.